# Does anyone have any experience working with the @material-ui/pickers Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

The reason I ask this question is because there seems to be no demo on how to use it. The documentation lacks any examples besides listing out the props: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/Calendar

I have my Calendar component so far using the moment.js library as per the demo for the Date Time Picker, also it appears that you need a date and an onChange so I added those as well using React.useState().

```
      <section>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
          libInstance={moment}
          utils={MomentUtils}
          locale="en"
        >
          <Calendar date={calendarDate} onChange={setCalendarDate} />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      </section>
```

I am getting many errors but it still seems like the root of the issue is that I can't figure out how to implement the Calendar component based on the limited docs. All ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example from documentation. https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/static-components

Anything doesn't work for you?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! Do you want me to close the issue?